# shouldStartLoadWithRequest not working in iOS

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm trying to override a url with the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.google.com/";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_udazzWebView loadRequest:urlRequest];
    NSLog(@"log");
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

    NSLog(@"log2");
    //use NSURLRequest object request , to manage the request.
    NSURL *urL=request.URL;
    NSString *urlStr=[urL absoluteString];
    NSLog(@"URLL %@",urlStr);
    if([urlStr isEqualToString:@"PostPicPopUp"]){
        NSLog(@"log3");
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Log2 doesn't appear in the console. I'm guessing it has something to do with replacing `NSURLRequest` in the `viewDidLoad`, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are just missing UIWebView delegates init like

```
- (void)initWebViewWithRect:(CGRect)rect {
    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    self.webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    self.webView.opaque=NO;
    self.webView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    self.webView.delegate=self;
    [self cleanSubViews];
}
```

You UIWebView should be defined like

```
@interface MXMBaseWebView()<UIWebViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate, MXMWebViewProgressDelegate> {
    CAGradientLayer *shadowLayer;
    MXMWebViewProgressView *_progressView;
    MXMWebViewProgress *_progressProxy;
    UIRefreshControl *_refreshControl;
}

@property(nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *webView;
@end
```

so you will do calls like

```
[self.webView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

At this point everything should work properly.